# Proving derivative tends to zero using 'Bloch's Theorem'.

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

I have been given the following version of the 'Bloch-Landau Theorem' in lectures:

Let $E=\lbrace z\in \mathbb{C}:|z|\leq 1\rbrace$. If $f:E\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is analytic and $f'(0)=1$, then $f(B(0,1))$ contains an open ball of radius $1/32$, where $B(0,1):=\lbrace z\in \mathbb{C}:|z|< 1\rbrace$.

I am trying to prove the following using the Bloch-Landau Theorem as given above:

Let $D=\lbrace z\in \mathbb{C}:|z|> 1\rbrace$ and $h:D\rightarrow B(0,1)$ be analytic. Then $h'(z)\rightarrow 0$ as $z\rightarrow \infty$.

I am rather stumped by how the Bloch-Landau Theorem can be used to prove this, since the domains $E$ and $D$ are complements of each other, and there appears to be no guarantee that h is has an inverse (even locally).

Any hints as to how to proceed would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just a thought: Considering $h\left(\frac1z\right)$ might be a sensible thing to do

Comment: This is not defined for $z=0$ and $|z|=1$. I know it can be extended to be an analytic function on $B(0,1)$, but is there any way to extend it to the CLOSED unit disc? Because to use the B-L theorem I need it be defined on closed unit disc.

Comment: For $0 < r < 1$ consider $f_r(z) = h\bigl(\frac{1}{rz}\bigr)$.

Comment: Okay, this leads to analytic map on closed unit disc, but then how to get $f_r'(0)=1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is easier than Bloch-Landau.

Hint: Define $g:\{0<|z|<1\} \to \{|z|<1\}$ by setting $g(z)=h(1/z).$ Then $g$ is bounded in $\{0<|z|<1\}.$ Hence $g$ has a removable singularity at $0 \dots$